Are regular hereditarily separable spaces Lindelöf?
I was wondering if $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$ (completely regular and $T_0$) hereditarily separable spaces are normal, or if there are any counterexamples. I didn't find any counterexamples and, searching further in $\pi$-Base, I checked that there aren't examples of regular hereditarily separable spaces that aren't hereditarily Lindelöf. Since regular hereditarily Lindelöf spaces are perfectly normal, and regularity and hereditarily separability are hereditary properties, I got more interested in asking first if anyone knows an example of a regular hereditarily separable space that isn't Lindelöf, or if regular hereditarily separable spaces are Lindelöf.

This is a well-known, rather complicated problem of extensive research.
A space is called S-space, if it is
regular Hausdorff, hereditarily separable and not hereditarily Lindelöf.

Vice versa, it is called L-space, if it is regular Hausdorff, hereditarily Lindelöf and not hereditarily separable.
L-spaces are completely regular, and I would guess that it doesn't make a big difference to require complete regularity for S-spaces as well. Perhaps they are even completely regular?
Of course, a non-hereditarily Lindelöf space contains a non-Lindelöf space. Hence, your question is equivalent to
(up to regularity or complete regularity, but this is irrelevant for the answer, see below):
Do S-spaces exist?
This question is related to:
Do L-spaces exist?

In fact, both questions become equivalent, if the notions are strengthened to what is called strong S-space and strong L-space.
Returning to S- or L-spaces,
the answer to both questions is yes under certain additional set-theoretic assumptions, e.g. (CH).
For instance, Hajnal and Juhász showed that under (CH) there exist 0-dimensional S- and L-spaces, in particular completely regular S-spaces.
However, in 1981 S. Todorčević showed the consistency of "there are no S-spaces", see here.
Hence, the big remaining question was, is it consistent that there are no L-spaces?
This question was finally solved by J. T. Moore, who showed the existence of an L-space in ZFC, see here.
There is an excellent survey article about S- and L-spaces by J. Roitman in the Handbook of set theoretic topology.
However, as it was written in 1984 (or before), it does not include Moore's solution to the L-space problem.
Also, a search for "L-space" / "S-space" will provide much more information about this subject.
Back to your question: concluding the above, the answer to your question is consistenly "yes" and consistenly "no".

Really interesting! Thank you so much, Ulli.
